# Python multiprocessing not working while for loop works

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am running multiprocessing to shorten my optimization time for multi periods.

Before I was using for loop, which is fast when my data is not large.

```
for date in DatesOpt:
  x = X.loc[X['Date'] == np.int(date)].drop('Date',1) 
  f = F.loc[F['Date'] == np.int(date)].drop('Date',1)
  d = D.loc[D['Date'] == np.int(date)].drop('Date',1)
  r = R.loc[R['Date'] == np.int(date)].drop('Date',1)
  optimize(date,x,f,d,r)
```

The optimize function outputs the optimized result to a csv file.

However, when I changed it to

```
if __name__=='__main__':
  pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()-1)
  for date in DatesOpt:
    x = X.loc[X['Date'] == np.int(date)].drop('Date',1) 
    f = F.loc[F['Date'] == np.int(date)].drop('Date',1)
    d = D.loc[D['Date'] == np.int(date)].drop('Date',1)
    r = R.loc[R['Date'] == np.int(date)].drop('Date',1)
    pool.apply_async(optimize,args=(date,x,f,d,r,))
  print('Waiting for all subprocesses done')
  pool.close()
  print('Pool Closed')
  pool.join()
  print('All subprocess done.')
```

everything just stops at the "Pool Closed" output and the optimizer never ends.

Is there any problem with this code?

Answer (score 2):

You are closing the pool before waiting, you better do it reversed:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
  pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()-1)
  for date in DatesOpt:
    x = X.loc[X['Date'] == np.int(date)].drop('Date',1) 
    f = F.loc[F['Date'] == np.int(date)].drop('Date',1)
    d = D.loc[D['Date'] == np.int(date)].drop('Date',1)
    r = R.loc[R['Date'] == np.int(date)].drop('Date',1)
    pool.apply_async(optimize,args=(date,x,f,d,r,))
  print('Waiting for all subprocesses done')
  pool.join()
  pool.close()
  print('Pool Closed')
  print('All subprocess done.')
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I tried the method and an error says: pool.join()

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 509, in join
    assert self._state in (CLOSE, TERMINATE)

AssertionError